# How to prevent someone from sending forms to my registration page? Is there even a point having capcha?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, security

so the way users register right now is:

index.php:
user fills in registration form -> enters capcha -> get redirected after form validation.

process.php:
all inputted data is processed (htmlentities, tagstrip, mysql escapes etc..) and it gets added to database.

So the question is: if user knows form variables, and where it's being posted = the capcha wont stop bots, they can simply create a file with assigned variables on their server and send thousands of requests to my process.php file and it will all get inserted.
So what's even the point of capcha if it doesn't stop really anyone?

So anyways - How can I prevent such scenario from happening?

Comment: They would need to have a valid Captcha everytime, same as a real user... But Thats not what a cpatcha is really for - its meant to prevent bots form submitting your form like a user. There are a number of libraries that allow you to mimic the functions of a browser so in that instance it would be jsut like a user hitting the page filling out the form and submitting it. What you need to do in combination with the Captcha is to generate a token that is validated that has to come from your server. Do a google and/or SO search for `csrf token`.

Comment: The whole point of a Captcha is that the correct value changes with each rendering. You only process the form if that value matches the value stored by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your server to generate a captcha-like string, save it to session or database and pass it across pages. If captcha is false then issue the error. Your imagination is the limit.

I use this type of captcha (php page as image). It is not bulletproof, but easy and does 99% of the job. As @Brad pointed out, you don't want to mess us the flow for the user, therefore the bad-user will be able to go around it.

```
<?php
/********************************************************
 * File:        captcha.php                             *
 * Author:      Yash Gupta (http://thetechnofreak.com)  *
 * Date:        12-Mar-2009                             *
 * Description: This file can be embedded as image      *
 *              to show CAPTCHA/                        *
 ********************************************************/

// The number of characters you
// want your CAPTCHA text to have
define('CAPTCHA_STRENGTH', 5);

/****************************
 *        INITIALISE        *
 ****************************/
// Tell PHP we're going to use
// Session vars
session_start();

// Md5 to generate the random string
$random_str = md5(microtime());

// Trim required number of characters
$captcha_str = substr($random_str, 0, CAPTCHA_STRENGTH);

// Allocate new image
$width = (CAPTCHA_STRENGTH * 10)+10;
$height = 20;

$captcha_img =ImageCreate($width, $height);

// ALLOCATE COLORS
// Background color-black
$back_color = ImageColorAllocate($captcha_img, 0, 0, 0);

// Text color-white
$text_color = ImageColorAllocate($captcha_img, 255, 255, 255);

// Line color-red
$line_color = ImageColorAllocate($captcha_img, 255, 0, 0);

/****************************
 *     DRAW BACKGROUND &amp;    *
 *           LINES          *
 ****************************/
// Fill background color
ImageFill($captcha_img, 0, 0, $back_color);

// Draw lines accross the x-axis
for($i = 0; $i < $width; $i += 5)
    ImageLine($captcha_img, $i, 0, $i, 20, $line_color);

// Draw lines accross the y-axis
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i += 5)
    ImageLine($captcha_img, 0, $i, $width, $i , $line_color);

/****************************
 *      DRAW AND OUTPUT     *
 *          IMAGE           *
 ****************************/
// Draw the random string
ImageString($captcha_img, 5, 5, 2, $captcha_str, $text_color);

// Carry the data (KEY) through session
$_SESSION['key'] = $captcha_str;

// Send data type
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

// Output image to browser
ImageJPEG($captcha_img);

// Free-Up resources
ImageDestroy($captcha_img);
?>
```

Comment: Is there any way I could make such capcha to work with Ajax? 
So that when user fills in form, enters capcha code -> clicks submit -> capcha gets validated via Ajax (dynamically) -> form is submitted or user is thrown error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CAPTCHA, you're verifying that CAPTCHA server-side.  It's not like you can just ignore its existence and send the other variables.  If you can, you have a very poor CAPTCHA implementation.

Even with a well-implemented CAPTCHA, what's the point?  You're right in that it doesn't stop *everyone*, but it will stop *most*.  The idea is that most bots just crawl the web posting form data until they find something that might be vulernable, for a human with malicious intent to follow up on later.  A good CAPTCHA, will prevent these initial bots from finding you.

There are plenty of ways around CAPTCHA though.  In addition to cracking them with an algorithm, it's often cheap enough to have real humans do it for you, such as via Mechanical Turk, or by presenting the CAPTCHA to users of another website and letting them do the work while thinking they are using that other site.

You won't stop all users who misbehave.  You can only to manage what you can.  At the end of the day, your site will have fake registrations and there is nothing you can do to completely prevent that.

Comment: Well the way I see capcha is: it just stops actual form on YOUR server from being submitted multiple times per second, while nothing stops really some guy to just enter website, copy form, remove capcha and launch script with same varaible names and action, is that right?

Comment: @arleitiss No, that isn't correct.  You should be denying form submission server-side if the CAPTCHA is wrong or not submitted.

Comment: Well the way I have capcha setup is:
User fills in the form, clicks submit (capcha gets validated with Ajax request, if it's correct - it submits form to process.php) if not, it throws error and refreshes capcha. 

So I guess I need to remake this whole thing then.

Comment: @arleitiss Yes, it sounds like it.  Alternatively, have your AJAX handler set something in `$_SESSION`, like `$_SESSION['captchaValidated']=true`.  If that isn't set when your form is submitted, then you know that they never hit the CAPTCHA... or that they have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: When Andrew mentioned SESSIONS, it striked me that I could easily just start session on index page, and validate the session on every step of registration. As far as I am aware - SESSIONS are completely invisible to clients therefore cannot be spoofed.

Comment: @arleitiss The session data is held server-side.  The fact that there is a session isn't completely invisible... the client has to have a cookie to reference the session data.  You have to use a session anyway for your CAPTCHA to work.  What I'm suggesting is that if you must, you can keep your CAPTCHA mechanism as-is, and just store in session data that the CAPTCHA is complete.